# Error al intentar mostrar una imagen traída de una api

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Estoy realizando una aplicacion con Asp.net la cual consume una api con JavaScript que me trae una imagen y deberia mostrar en mi front, la imagen que traigo se encuentra ubicada en un archivo diferente al de la api, cuando realizo la peticion me genera un error el cual dice, Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/imagenes/perfil/descarga.png, pero cuando pego esa misma direccion en el navegador me muestra la imagen sin problemas:
Este es mi codigo .net:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string nombreArchivo)
{
    string directorio = "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\imagenes\";
    string ruta = directorio + nombreArchivo;
    if (File.Exists(ruta))
    {
        var result = new
        {
            imagen = ruta.Replace('\\', '/')
        }
        return Ok(result);
    };
    else
    {
        var result = new
        {
            imagen = "No existe la imagen"
        };
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo con cual realizo la peticion:

```
const foto = document.querySelector('.imagenn');
const file = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:64108/api/Archivos/?nombreArchivo=perfil/descarga.png`);
    const datos = await res.json();

    foto.style.backgroundImage = `url('${datos.imagen}')`;
};

file();
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde Javascript, por seguridad no se permite el acceso a ficheros locales de la maquina que está navegando, por eso el error de not allowed. Las imágenes, en este caso deberían servirse desde el servidor, en este caso, localhost.

No es un error de código si no de concepto.

Comment: entonces no hay una forma directa de obtener la imagen?

Comment: desde c:/ no, es imposible por seguridad. Lo que debes hacer es servirla desde el servidor. Por ejemplo, en lugar de c:/imagenes/mi-imagen.jpg el path debe ser http://localhost/imagenes/mi-imagen.jpg